# How to view killed threads in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have by mistake killed a running thread in mysql db .

How do i see the killed threads in mysql ?

Can i investigate who granted the access to some user .

Answer (score 0):

Your only chance is to use:

SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST command and then under command column you May see "Killed". If you see that you still have a chance to do a roll back. If thread is Dead and you cannot see killed state then it's too late.